# How can I block suspicious traffic from Amazon?

Tags: traffic, amazon, block

Could someone please tell me, very simply, how to block Amazon Technologies Inc from accessing my webpage. I was hit last week by a very unusual surge of traffic, with another visit a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this article on blocking AWS with .htaccess](https://www.webmasterworld.com/webmaster/3848988.htm).  The solutions there is to add the following to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*amazonaws\.com [OR]    
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^.*\.compute-1\.amazonaws\.com$ [NC,OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "AISearchBot" [NC,OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "woriobot" [NC,OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "heritrix" [NC,OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "NetSeer" [NC,OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Nutch" [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately Adobe own the webspace, and so I can see I will need to wait for them to respond and offer some advice. Thank you again.